# Suggest a static class as the value source of a properties of another type

Tags: c#, intellisense

I have this class:

```
public struct Escapes
{
    private readonly string Value;
    private Escapes(string value) => Value = value;
    public static implicit operator string(Escapes r) => r.Value;
    public override string ToString() => Value;

    public static readonly Escapes LineFeed = new Escapes("\n");
    public static readonly Escapes CarriageReturn = new Escapes(new Escapes("\r"));
    public static readonly Escapes Digit = new Escapes(@"\d");
    public static readonly Escapes NotADigit = new Escapes(@"\D");
    public static readonly Escapes WordChar = new Escapes(@"\w");
    //……………

    public static Escapes AsciiChar(byte asciiCode)
    {
        return new Escapes( @"\x" + Convert.ToString(asciiCode, 16).PadLeft(2, '0'));
    }

    public static Escapes Unicode(short uniCode)
    {
        return new Escapes(@"\u" + Convert.ToString(uniCode, 16).PadLeft(4, '0'));
    }
}
```

I also have this class:

```
public class CharOrEscape
{
    public string Value;
    private CharOrEscape(string value) => Value = value;
    public static implicit operator CharOrEscape(Escapes s) => new CharOrEscape(s.ToString());
    public static implicit operator CharOrEscape(char c) => new CharOrEscape(c.ToString());
    public static implicit operator string(CharOrEscape s) => s.ToString();
    public override string ToString() => Value;
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => ((CharOrEscape)obj).Value == Value;
}
```

I want to tell the intellisense that any property or a parameter of type `CharOrEscape` accepts values of type Escapes so that the auto complete list offers members of the Escapes class.

I saw a code like that once using some attributes, but I lost the project and couldn't find it again by google search.

Comment: referring to the static members of the `Escape` struct needs mentioning the struct name anyway, so is it not sufficient to just write `CharOrEscape x = Escapes.` and have the autocompletion? or do you mean something else?

Comment: Aside: [Implicit Conversion Operators are Bad](https://netvignettes.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/implicit-conversion-operators-are-bad/). And please don't have public fields. And your `CharOrEscape.Equals` implementation is badly broken.

Comment: Could class `CharOrEscape` simply inherit class `Escapes`?

Comment: I want CharOrEscape to deal with a Char or a Escapes as the name suggests. So, Inheritance will not solve the problem, unless we have miltiple inheritance in C#!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the request correctly you could just comment the properties of `CharOrEscape` with something like this

```
///<summary></summary>
///<typeparamref name="Escapes"/>
public string Value;
...
```

You can read more on the [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/typeparamref)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Intellisence still offers no suggestions when I use valriables of the CharOrEscape type.

Comment: In the past you had to add a `/doc` flag to the compiler but now days I believe it is automatic. This may help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc

Comment: I don't want to view some info in a toool tip. I want the auto compleat list to pop up and offer the members of the the Escapes when the user assigns any avlue to a variable or a param of type CharOrEscape. Of cource things will be easier if we can define a variable with a constarint that allow it to have values of more that one type! I use the CharOrEscape as a workaround to do that.

Comment: So you are looking for Visual Studio to understand and show that CharOrEscape is-a Escape?

Comment: I saw a project that defines a class with properties that return Regex with presefined patterns, and made the intellisense offer values from this calss when assigning a value to a Regex valriable. I failed to find this project again!

Comment: If the standard way of adding custom code to Intellisense (i.e. XML comments) then my best guess extension methods were being used somehow or the project leveraged ReSharper and you didn't realize it was installed. I'd be very interested in seeing the code you had seen before though.